# Webpack won't parse JSX no matter what I try

Tags: reactjs, webpack, jsx

Been at it a couple days...

Trying to use Webpack to do lazy-loading of React modules, app-shell rendered first on the server, then Router injected on the client. It was compiling fine when using gulp, but with Webpack, I get the infamous:

ERROR in ../server/components/routes/AppRouter.jsx
Module parse failed: /web/sites/react-lazy/server/components/routes/AppRouter.jsx Unexpected token (11:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

AppRouter.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import routes from './AppRoute.jsx';
import createMemoryHistory from 'history/lib/createMemoryHistory';

if (typeof require.ensure !== 'function') require.ensure = (d, c) => c(require)

export default class AppRouter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router routes={routes} history={createMemoryHistory()} /> // < -- errors here
    ); 
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname + "/src",
  entry: './js/app.es6.js',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [ 
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/js'),
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        query: {
          presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    publicPath: '/build',
    filename: 'app.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',
  }
}
```

My directory structure:

```
  /
    webpack.config.js
    .babelrc
    /src
       /js
          app.es6.js
          .babelrc // <-- also put a .babelrc here in case
```

My package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.14.0", 
    "webpack": "^1.13.2",
    ...
 }
```

I've tried:

- duplicating the .babelrc file into the main directory and entry point directory, not sure which is necessary.
- registering
  babel-register: in app.es6.js:

  ```
  require('babel-register')({
    presets: [ 'es2015', 'stage-0', 'react' ]
  });
  ```
- runnning webpack with '--config webpack.config.js' argument
- If I downgrade the babel, babel-core, and babel-loader version to 5.* (from 6.*), there is a different error:

  ```
  ERROR in ./js/app.es6.js
  Module build failed: ReferenceError: [BABEL] /web/sites/react-lazy/src/js/app.es6.js: Unknown option: direct.presets
  ```

I'm fairly new to React and webpack, I should say. Anyone know any other tricks?

**Solution:**

- webpack config's 'include' property must include all directories you need to pass through loaders

Comment: Did you install babel-preset-es2015?

Comment: Yes, sorry, updated with package.json

Comment: This is quite curious. Everything seems to be right as far as I know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entry file uses components that are located here:

```
/web/sites/react-lazy/server/components/
```

However, your `include` configuration only allows files below `/web/sites/react-lazy/src/js/` to be passed to the loader (`include` means: *"any files that should be passed to this loader **must** be located in this directory*").

So either remove the `include` configuration, or make it an array that also includes the other locations where .jsx files can be found.